# use ldapsearch gssapi ldap_sasl_interactive_bind_s error

Tags: ldap, openldap

Use  `ldapsearch    -Y GSSAPI   -h ihuorong.com -U zxx@xx.com -w 'Abc123qwe' -b 'DC=ihuorong,DC=com' '(objectClass=computer)'` command bind windows ldap server, get this error message

"ldap_sasl_interactive_bind_s: Local error (-2)
additional info: SASL(-1): generic failure: GSSAPI Error: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information (No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: KEYRING:persistent:0))"

But use windows LDAPAdmin can use GSSAPI connect the Server.
So it's werid.

Comment: I thought the idea with GSSAPI was that you would not specify a password, but would run kinit first to authenticate the user.

Comment: I use kinit is successful,but the new error is occur    ```Minor code may provide more information (Server not found in Kerberos database)``` I  use klist ```kdb5_util dump``` can get the list content